# Skip IP only if to much time elapsed Keepalived

Tags: failover, virtual-ip-address, keepalived

I have 2 servers (A and B), where A is a master. This are haproxy servers if important.
I want keepalived to skip the VIP from A to B only if A was down for more than 15 seconds.
I saw the `advert_int` option but unless I am using it incorrectly it doesn't work.
also tried adjusting the `fall`, `rise`, and `interval` values of the `vrrp_script` block.
Here is my config:

```
vrrp_script check {
  script "[...]"
  interval 7
  weight 2
  rise 4
  fall 4
}

vrrp_instance VI_1 {
  advert_int 6
  state MASTER
  interface eth0
  virtual_router_id 78
    priority 101
    authentication {
    auth_type AH
    auth pass pass
  }

  unicast _src_ip 1.1.1.2

  unicast_peer{
    1.1.1.3
  }

  virtual_ipaddress {
    1.1.1.1
  }

  track_script {
    check
  }
}
```